# How can I declare and initialize an array of pointers to a structure in C?

Tags: c, null, pointers, malloc, structure

I have a small assignment in C. I am trying to create an array of pointers to a structure. My question is how can I initialize each pointer to NULL? Also, after I allocate memory for a member of the array, I can not assign values to the structure to which the array element points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node list_node_t;

struct list_node
{
   char *key;
   int value;
   list_node_t *next;
};


int main()
{

   list_node_t *ptr = (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));

   ptr->key = "Hello There";
   ptr->value = 1;
   ptr->next = NULL;

   // Above works fine

   // Below is erroneous 

   list_node_t **array[10] = {NULL};      

   *array[0] =  (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
    array[0]->key = "Hello world!";  //request for member ‘key’ in something not a structure or union
    array[0]->value = 22;            //request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union 
    array[0]->next = NULL;           //request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union


    // Do something with the data at hand
    // Deallocate memory using function free 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here:

```
list_node_t **array[10] = {NULL};
```

You're declaring an array of 10 pointers to pointers to your struct. What you want is an array of 10 pointers to your struct:

```
list_node_t *array[10] = {NULL};
```

It's confusing because yes, `array` really is a pointer to a pointer, but the square bracket notation sort of abstracts that away for you in C, and so you should think of `array` as just an array of pointers.

You also don't need to use the dereference operator on this line:

```
*array[0] =  (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
```

Because C dereferences it for you with its bracket notation. So it should be:

```
array[0] =  (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
```

Comment: That's a good answer, except that `array` is **not** "really a pointer to a pointer".  `array` is really an array, not a pointer of any sort.  Array types when used in an expression are evaluated to a pointer to the array's first element, but an array is still a real type, distinct from pointers.  `sizeof array` should help convince you that `array` is not a pointer.

Comment: instead of `array[0] = (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));` it should be `array[0] = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));` Don't typecast malloc calls.

Comment: only the first element of array is pointer , its special pointer called **self pointer" its actually constant self pointer which points to first element to keep track of starting address of an array.

Answer (score 4):

The line `list_node_t **array[10] = {NULL};` is wrong - here you declare *array of pointers to pointers to list nodes*. Replace that with:

```
list_node_t *array[10] = { NULL };
```

and it should work.